# Динамический поиск в поле фильтра Django

Tags: django, поиск, фильтрация

Всем привет. Организовал фильтрацию в django по нескольким полям таблицы, все работает отлично, но столкнулся с такой проблемой:  В выпадающем списке поля "Здание" (скрин ниже) в будущем будет очень много позиций, поэтому листать вниз весь список и искать необходимое здание вручную будет довольно проблематично. В связи с чем возник вопрос, возможно ли конкретно в это поле к выпадающему списку добавить добавить строку поиска, в котором пользователь сможет писать необходимое ему значение и выбирать из тех пунктов, которые будут выдаваться ему по вхождению введенного им текста?

Вот как это выглядит сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас в этом поле можно выбирать только имеющиеся значения, т.к. оно является внешним ключом другой таблицы. Мне бы хотелось реализовать это таким образом, чтобы в это поле можно было ввести, например, "1", и в выпадающем списке осталось "стр.1" и "стр.1666". Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

views.py:

```
def device_rooms_search(request):
    device_rooms = DeviceRooms.objects.all()
    deviceRoomsFilter = DeviceRoomsFilter(request.GET, queryset=device_rooms)
    device_rooms = deviceRoomsFilter.qs
    context = {'device_rooms_list': device_rooms, 'deviceRoomsFilter': deviceRoomsFilter}
    return render(request, "database/device_rooms/device_rooms_search.html", context)
```

filters.py:

```
class DeviceRoomsFilter(df.FilterSet):
    name = df.CharFilter(field_name='room_number', label='Имя помещения', lookup_expr='icontains')
    descr = df.CharFilter(field_name='description', label='Примечание', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceRooms
        fields = ['name', 'facility_id', 'building_id', 'device_room_type', 'descr']
```

forms.py:

```
class DeviceRoomsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceRooms
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'id': 'Уникальный идентификатор комнаты',
            'room_number': 'Имя помещения',
            'device_room_type': 'Название предприятия',
            'building_id': 'Идентификатор здания',
            'facility_id': 'Идентификатор предприятия',
            'description': 'Примечание (опционально)',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceRoomsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['facility_id'].empty_label = "Выберите предприятие..."
        self.fields['id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()  # скрываем поле id для пользователя
        self.fields['room_number'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = "Введите имя помещения"
        self.fields['building_id'].empty_label = "Выберите здание..."
        self.fields['device_room_type'].empty_label = "Выберите тип помещения..."
        self.fields['description'].required = False
        self.fields['room_number'].error_messages = {
            'unique': "Выбранное имя помещения уже используется, введите другое имя",
        }
```

models.py:

```
class DeviceRooms(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=7, primary_key=True)
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    device_room_type = models.ForeignKey(DeviceRoomTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    building_id = models.ForeignKey(Buildings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    facility_id = models.ForeignKey(Facilities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["room_number"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_room_type
```

device_room_search.html:

```
<form method="get" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div style="text-align: center">
      {% for field in deviceRoomsFilter.form %}
              {% if field.name == 'name' %}
                    Имя помещения: {{ field }}
              {% endif %}
              {% if field.name == 'facility_id' %}
                    Предприятие: {{ field }}
              {% endif %}
              {% if field.name == 'building_id' %}
                    Здание: {{field}}
              {% endif %}
              {% if field.name == 'device_room_type' %}
                    Тип помещения: {{ field }}
              {% endif %}
              {% if field.name == 'descr' %}
                    Примечание: {{ field }}
              {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй использовать Django-Select2 https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
там есть тот функционал, который тебе нужен.